# How to make entire link clickable in an unordered list

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list of links and I need to make the whole list item clickable.

```
<li><a href="blah">This</a></li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69wzksdq/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you have is that padding is being applied to your `li` elements. Here is a fiddle with the whole area being clickable (simplified your border-bottom rule as well): https://jsfiddle.net/eowznujs/

Comment: What is the operational usage for the `1em` padding on the `a` tag?

Comment: @BillyFerguson At this point I was only assuming it was using the default `font-size` as a `padding` value. Using `16px` instead of `1em` would be fine as well, but say you changed the `font-size` on your `ul`, the size of the text as well as the padding would be affected.

Answer (score 1):

use the css

```
li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

now I see, that you know this. your problem is padding on li element. just assign padding: 0 to the li element and apply padding to the li a selector like this

```
li { padding: 0 }
li a { padding: 16px; }
```

Comment: I think the issue OP is asking about is why the `a` does not fill the `li` with `height: auto`

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```css
 #groupchats ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    #groupchats li{
      border-bottom:1.5px solid #69f0ae;
      background-color: #006064;
      display: block;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #groupchats li:last-child { border-bottom: none; }

    #groupchats li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 16px;
      color: white;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="row col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="groupchats">


  <div id="groupchat-errors">


  </div>
    <ul id="groupchat-index" "demo-list-item mdl-list"> 
      <li class="mdl-list__item"><a href="/groupchats/estset">one</a></li>
<li class="mdl-list__item"><a href="/groupchats/meandjess">two</a></li>
<li class="mdl-list__item"><a href="/groupchats/nooooo">three</a></li>

</div>
```